# Python requests html 403 response

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Im using the requests module in python to try and make a search on the following webiste http://musicpleer.audio/, however this website appears to be blocking me as it issues nothing but a 403 when i attempt to access it, im wondering how i can get around this, ive tried sending it the user agent of my web browser(chrome) and it still returns error 403. any suggestions on how i could get around this an example of downloading a song from the site would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

My code:

```
import requests, os

def funGetList:
    start_path = 'C:/Users/Jordan/Music/' # current directory
    list = []
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk(start_path):
        for filename in files:
            temp = (os.path.join(path,filename))
            tempLen = len(temp)
            "print(tempLen)"
            iterate = 0
            list.append(temp[22:(len(temp))-4])

def funDownloadMP3:
    for i in list:
        print(i)

    payload = {'searchQuery': 'meme', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
    url = 'http://musicpleer.audio/'
    print(requests.post(url, data=payload))
```

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` generally means you need to authenticate to use service. `User-Agent` is a header not usually part of the `data` payload. Are you sure you need to `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `User-Agent` in the headers seems to work:

```
In []:
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://musicpleer.audio/'
r = requests.get('{}#!{}'.format(url, 'meme'), headers=headers)
r.status_code

Out[]:
200
```

Note: It looks like the search url is simple `'#!<search-term>'`

Answer (score 0):

[HTML 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) Forbidden error code.
The server might be expecting some more request headers like Host or Cookies etc.
You might want to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to debug it with ease